# tkinter - grid item won't move beyond column 0 on a scrollable Canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to mass populate items on a scrollable Canvas. When I create a function to create image labels and buttons, everything works fine if they are on column 0.

If I set it to column 1 however, it stays in the same place. I thought it would have something to do with the frame, so I tried changing the size of the frame, the size of the buttons etc. to be bigger and make the frame bigger as well making the canvas_window bigger. Nothing worked!

```
def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, background="black", width=230)
frame = Frame(canvas, background="white")
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both")
vsb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw")

frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

# --- Function that populates the frame
def standard_window(frame):
    block_name = ["Ixalan", "Amonkhet", "Kaladesh"]
    button_command = [test]
    first_set_photo = ["ixalan.png", "amonkhet.png", "kaladesh.png"]
    second_set_photo = ["ixalan.png", "hour.png", "aether_revolt.png"]
    third_set_photo = []
    set_1_count = 1
    file_count = 0
    count = 0
    image_row = 0
    while count < len(block_name):

        photo = PhotoImage(file="{0}".format(first_set_photo[count]))
        label = Label(frame, image=photo, fg="white", bg="black")
        label.image = photo
        label.grid(row=image_row, column=1)
        Button(frame, text="{0} BLOCK".format(block_name[file_count]), font=("Helvetica", 8), fg="white", bg="black", command=test).grid(
            row = set_1_count, column=0, columnspan=5)
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] instead of a couple of disjoint blocks of code.

Comment: Also, please post code that actually works, and preferably code that doesn't depend on images (for the [mcve], just use text instead of images). Finally, the code you posted doesn't seem to use any column but zero, so it's hard to understand why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: One last thing: are you aware that columns that are empty have a width of zero?  You could put something at column 10,000 and it would still be on the far left if there's nothing in the other columns.